# Total coverage won't increase even after exclusions

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have noticed the total coverage doesn't increase even after exclude un covered lines.

What I have noticed after exclusions was, after exclusions the number of `Lines to cover` and `Uncovered Lines` both got reduced. So looks like that impact the total coverage remain same.

Further after exclusions those files DO NOT appear under files as expected which confirms exclusions working properly.

[image: Coverage stats]

Can someone please explain what's the theory behind and how exclusions can increase the total coverage

Comment: It would be impossible to say without knowing a great deal about the project in question.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr What sort of more details will help. As mentioned all the exclusions, has been removed from the Sonar side. I assume that implies data transfer from Project to Sonar is good.

Comment: Someone would have to examine the entire project. I would continue to provide details in the sonarsource forum thread that you started for this.